# PDF.js - Slow rendering for scanned image PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, pdf.js

One of our intranet web apps process a lot of documents and I am testing PDF.js(Mozilla) and see if we can use this instead of Adobe reader.(Our official web browser in our work place is IE and we have been having some issues with Adobe reader whenever we upgrade IE because each user has different version of Adobe reader in his/her machine.)

So far, PDF.js worked fine with FF and Chrome, but IE10/IE11 give me a little of problem with scanned image PDF file. If I run the helloworld.html with a sample scanned image PDF file(hard-coded URL), it take about 5-6 sec per page under Tomcat7, so if takes around 15 sec for three pages of scanned doc. Of course FF and Chrome are blazing fast.

Has anyone faced this type of issue with IE?

Thanks in advance